# simulator gets hung and does not show any error when not connected to internet

Tags: codenameone

I'm having issue with simulator gets hung when internet gets disconnected to my laptop. Some times even menu buttons are unresposive. Agian it starts working immediately laptop connects to internet. Does Connectivity.isConnected() method have any issues on simulator when internet disconnected. Please let me know if any on have similar issue.

following error message shows up after gets connected to internet in Log for trying the menu options:

```
EDT violation detected!
EDT violation detected!
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:699)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.createFont(JavaSEPort.java:5629)
at com.codename1.ui.Font.<init>(Font.java:99)
at com.codename1.ui.Font.createSystemFont(Font.java:345)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.loadTheme(Resources.java:1351)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFileImpl(Resources.java:305)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFile(Resources.java:271)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:191)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:742)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:679)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.ComponentTreeInspector.<init>(ComponentTreeInspector.java:75)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$18.actionPerformed(JavaSEPort.java:2682)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:842)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:886)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use that API from start/init. It can block while checking and effectively crash your app. The start/init methods need to finish execution cleanly.

The component inspector works off the EDT thread so it violates it. It doesn't really matter for production since you don't have a component inspector on the device...

Comment: Shai..I'm not using Connectivity.isConnected()  method in Start() or init(). I'm just mentioning that when internet is not connected, screen froze and non-responsive. Please advise this is not only happening when "component inspector" is used but also while doing other events on the Mobile App. Please advise.

Comment: Shai..update on this is it is happening even with internet connected with JDK 1.8.152. I'm not sure if something from JDK is conflicting.

Comment: If this happens in the simulator just reproduce this and press pause in the debugger. Look at the stack traces and see what's blocking.